# View html file in cmd

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, html

How can someone view an html file in cmd? I mean preview the file or code and not open it with the default browser. Something like

```
echo "<h1>foo title</h1>"
```

where the "foo title" will look like an h1 tag element as it would in a browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for: `type` or `more` will show the raw file with all its tags, but the `cmd` environment does not have all the enhancements you will need to show different text renderings that a browser or `word` has. What's wrong with these? The best you can hope for is an interpreter that will render the tags as different colours or text enhancements (underline, blinking, etc). Is this what you want? If not, what?

Comment: @AFH why are you telling him about `type` or `more` when he has already said he knows about `echo` and he is asking about parsing html. So `type` and `more` do nothing more re what he is looking for, than echo does.  Also, (since you mention blinking and underlines), do you know of a program that parses html and makes bigger text blink or puts underscores under it?  And anyhow, if he wanted to distinguish it he could replace <h1> with *  and <h2> with ** but he isn't asking how to do that.

Comment: @barlop - I asked because I did not understand what he was asking (especially since the `echo` example was syntactically incorrect in HTML): I tried to clarify his options, since I was not prepared to search for programs which may well not meet his needs. I would not have asked if I had seen your edited answer, which covers the ground admirably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible from pure command line output, (so you wouldn't be able to do `echo "<h1>asdf</h1>" | ShowAsHtml`  as a program to show whatever as html  would require changing the font size which would affect all text.

The next question is whether it is possible in cmd, from within a program. (Some programs have their own environment within cmd that isn't part of the shell.. so e.g. if you ever ran Doom or Wolfenstein 3D or Wolfenstein then when you exit it you don't see the graphics hanging there in the shell, it just goes back to the shel.. similarly a program liek dosshell which was a file manager)

So it might be possible from within a program within cmd.

Games e.g. Xenon 2, have often had elaborate graphics, so must support fonts in theory.

There was at one time a program by pcmag, called banner.exe which would display text in large size, with lots of extended ascii characters on multiple lines, so that'd be evidence that from pure command line output you can't.

Another thing to think about is Tex, does any cmd version of that do it, it seems none exist. There's no PDF viewer from cmd.exe either. On the other hand, there are games with good graphics.

The two famous command line web browsers are  links and lynx, they're used often on linux, and both have windows cmd implementations. Neither of them show different font sizes.

As you can see

Here is an example from links, http://links.twibright.com/download.php  available http://links.twibright.com/download/binaries/win32/

[image]

And for Lynx

http://www.vordweb.co.uk/standards/download_lynx.htm

[image]

At one time there was ANSI escape sequences, but even those which could get different colours, couldn't.

There were some commands you could do it in debug, and win7 32bit comes with debug, you could do e.g. -f b800:0 FA0 21 CE`  to send bytes to VRAM - video ram, and get different colours of flashing text. But not different font sizes. (or different fonts).

It's definitely impossible as command line output, but may be possible from within a program in cmd.exe just liek a game can.  But the two well known command line web browsers don't do it, and maybe none exist. But I wouldn't rule it out. One reason why one might not exist is that implementing HTML is a project in itself, including margins for example, and it's not likely to be done just for headers / the H tag.

Something like

[image]

would've shown in DOS, and I think in cmd.exe 32bit (I have a non 64-bit xenon2 that I can't test in my 64bit win7 but I might have run in win7 32bit or more likely with dosbox).   But I think nobody has implemented what you ask, as HTML support might require some standard fonts as well, so maybe it's quite a bit of work to do that graphics in cmd, and it hasn't been done.  (that kind of graphics, desktop publishing like graphics might've been done in a desktop publishing app, but I never used one and it hasn't been done for html. If it existed then it'd be more well known than lynx or links)